# Maximum number of vectors in $\mathbb R^n$ that are at least an angle $\theta$ apart

Tags: linear-algebra, spherical-geometry

In a space $\mathbb R^n$, how many vectors can you fit that are at least an angle $\theta$ apart, where $\theta>0$?

For example, in $\mathbb R^2$, the maximum number of vectors that are at least angle $\theta = 2/3$ radians apart is just $2\pi/\theta=2\pi/(2/3)=3\pi$ vectors (rounding down, that's $9$ vectors). How do I find the maximum number of vectors that are at least that angle apart in $n$ dimensions?

Comment: Technically the only $\theta$ for which there exist more than two vectors must be $2\pi/3$ since for every other $\theta$ there will be at least two vectors with $\theta_1\ne\theta_2\mod{}2\pi$.

Comment: There's a misunderstanding. I edited my question to reflect what I'm looking for.

Comment: This is equivalent to the problem of finding optimal [spherical codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_code), for which no general solution is known.